# OS X Mail/iOS Mail adds lots of padding to notification e-mails

Tags: feature-request, notifications, email

My notification e-mails look great on the Gmail web version, but they aren't so nice on the OS X mail app, or on iOS. When I look at them, **there is a lot of extra padding** on the top and bottom parts, whereas **when I look at them with Gmail, there isn't**.

I'm using Mail Version 7.0 (1822) on OS X 10.9 build 13A603

[image: Rendering issue on OS X]
[image: Rendering issues on iOS]

Comment: Do you assign tasks to yourself? :) (*you* are the iOS developer...)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd it's actually not an iOS issue, but rather an HTML/CSS problem.

Comment: Can we get some freehand circles (preferably in red) to show where the issue is?

Comment: +1: nice freehand circles

Comment: The house and the smiley are awesome, but I can't decide if that's extravagant hair or low flying smoke...